# PLACEHOLDER -- Pipedream: Connect Stack Exchange with 100s of other Applications

Tags: app, placeholder

Do more with the StackExchange API. We recently integrated StackExchange with Pipedream.

Pipedream is a serverless integration and compute platform. We provide a free, hosted platform that makes it easy to connect apps and develop, execute and maintain event-driven workflows. The platform has over 300 fully integrated applications with managed authentication and support for over 1M npm packages.

Key Features:

- [Event Sources](https://github.com/PipedreamHQ/pipedream#event-sources) - Open source [components](https://github.com/PipedreamHQ/pipedream/tree/master/components) that emit events from services (Github, Slack, Airtable, RSS & more)
- [Workflows](https://github.com/PipedreamHQ/pipedream#workflows) - A sequence of linear steps - just Node.js code - triggered by an event (via event source, HTTP or timer)
- [Actions](https://github.com/PipedreamHQ/pipedream#actions) - Pre-built code steps that you can use in a workflow to perform common operations across Pipedream's 300+ API integrations, for example: sending email, adding a row to a Google Sheet, and more.
- [Destinations](https://github.com/PipedreamHQ/pipedream#destinations) - Deliver events asynchronously to common destinations like Amazon S3, Snowflake, HTTP and email
- Serverless - No server or cloud resources to manage
- [Free](https://github.com/PipedreamHQ/pipedream#pricing) - No fees for individual developers (see [limits](https://docs.pipedream.com/limits/))

Product Demo: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJ-KRbp6EO8&feature=youtu.be) (5 minutes)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Apps! I didn't downvote, but this post could be improved a lot by focusing on your product's integration with Stack Exchange instead of being (essentially) an advertisement.

Comment: The reason this is a placeholder is because we haven't completed the integration.  Once we do, we will post more clarity.  Apologies for the generic post.

Comment: @Pipedream Post when you're done, perhaps? I personally am interested in your project.